# Git - What's the branch I'm merging from?

Tags: git

How to get name of the branch I'm merging from? **git status** tells me only that I'm merging, but I forgot what branch exactly I'm merging...

```
On branch master
Your branch is up-to-date with 'origin/master'.
All conflicts fixed but you are still merging.
  (use "git commit" to conclude merge)
```

Comment: Try with `git log` ?

Comment: Nah, already tried that. Doesn't show.

Comment: `xargs git log --decorate --no-walk=unsorted --oneline < .git/MERGE_HEAD`

Comment: @PetSerAl It worked! Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it clear for everyone who still seek for similar answer

The answer was posted as comment by @PetSerAL

```
xargs git log --decorate --no-walk=unsorted --oneline < .git/MERGE_HEAD
```

Answer (score 2):

try [git show-branch](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-show-branch)

It show a list of branches and the last commit on each. 
If there is a merge it show a `-` in the merge.

Answer (score 0):

```
 ​git show MERGE_HEAD -s --pretty=%d
```